# After adding meta_box, how allow admin user to create multiple ones (i.e. create array of that type)? Like adding new custom fields of the same name

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a function that is called on the hook `add_meta_boxes` which creates a new meta type `employee` (this is just an testing example) which shows inputs for `name`, `department` and `picture`. But I don't want to add just one, I want to also have a button for the admin user to create another `employee`, so that on the page, in the loop, I can get an array of the meta_key `employee`.

Is the only way to do this, to insert a script and button, so that on button press, the JavaScript creates all the inputs via the DOM? Or is there a "Wordpress-Official" api/function for doing this?

I want something like:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| Employee                                                        |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Name: ____________________                                     |
|  Department: ____________________                               |
|  Picture: browse...                                             |
|  --------                                                       |
|  | Save |                                                       |
|  --------                                                       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------

------------------------
| Add Another Employee |
------------------------
```

Comment: Answers: 1) Yes. 2) No.

Comment: @brasofilo thanks. too bad, it doesn't feel "clean".

Answer (score 0):

A "cleaner" way to do this, would be to create a number of custom post types, and link them using Posts 2 Posts [1] - then you can do nicer things.

Meta is an easy way to do stuff, but I find you eventually end up regretting the choice to do it that way.

[1] http://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts/